# How to display an id item from another controller to other controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, controller, parameter-passing

i already pass an id from room to booking controller,

```
 <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Bookings", new { id = item.RoomID })'" class="btn btn-info">Book</button>
```

now i want to display that id, to other controller after click book button, here is the image 
[image: i want to display this item]

now, i want to past to another controlle which display the id as text, and show here, but the image didnt show the details. [image]

here is my code in booking controller ,

```
 public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        var bookings = db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Room).Include(b => b.Register);



        ViewBag.RoomID = new SelectList(db.Rooms, "RoomID", "RoomType");
        ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Registers, "id", "username");
        return View();
    }
```

what i should do to display the details of room id in booking controller?

here is the code for view, 
[image]

Comment: You can create a viewmodel and pass required values when returning view, but I want to see view code containing dropdownlists and date textbox as shown in your image.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto see my update, already add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set selected value from controller.

```
    public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        var bookings = db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Room).Include(b => b.Register);

        ViewBag.RoomID = new SelectList(db.Rooms, "RoomID", "RoomType", id);
        ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Registers, "id", "username");
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some possible concerns in your code:

1) Avoid using viewmodel property name as `ViewBag` property name, as this may cause confusion between both of them.

2) You're not populate anything inside `DropDownList` helper by setting second parameter to null value, use `ViewBag` properties containing `SelectList` or `List<SelectListItem>` to populate it.

3) Use strongly-typed `DropDownListFor` for each viewmodel properties.

Based from those points above, the controller action should be like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    var bookings = db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Room).Include(b => b.Register);

    var model = new ViewModel();

    // use query to get both selected IDs
    model.RoomId = bookings.Where(...).Select(x => x.RoomId).FirstOrDefault();
    model.CustomerId = bookings.Where(...).Select(x => x.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();

    ViewBag.RoomList = new SelectList(db.Rooms, "RoomID", "RoomType");
    ViewBag.CustomerList = new SelectList(db.Registers, "id", "username");
    return View(model);
}
```

And both dropdownlists should use strongly-typed helper as in example below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoomId, ViewBag.RoomList as SelectList, "-- Select Room --", new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, ViewBag.CustomerList as SelectList, "-- Select Customer --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Note: Better to populate option lists inside viewmodel properties which have `SelectList`/`List<SelectListItem>` type and pass it directly to view:

**Model**

```
public List<SelectListItem> RoomList { get; set; }

public List<SelectListItem> CustomerList { get; set; }
```

**Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    var bookings = db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Room).Include(b => b.Register);

    var model = new ViewModel();

    // use query to get both selected IDs
    model.RoomId = bookings.Where(...).Select(x => x.RoomId).FirstOrDefault();
    model.CustomerId = bookings.Where(...).Select(x => x.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();

    model.RoomList = db.Rooms.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.RoomType, Value = x.RoomID }).ToList();
    model.CustomerList = db.Registers.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.username, Value = x.id }).ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoomId, Model.RoomList, "-- Select Room --", new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, Model.CustomerList, "-- Select Customer --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: but i want to show the value in text, not dropdownlist, any idea on how to get it ?